# Memory Leak in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks

I have a memory leak in my WPF application. The application consists of a `TabControl`, where the content of each tab is a `usercontrol`. I have analyzed the memory with [Redgate Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=non-brand&utm_campaign=ANTSMemoryProfiler&gclid=Cj0KEQjw5syiBRCwxPbE6o_MsK4BEiQAUowjpi3fg7vuBg5d_O9xx07EvwzpDhy6ro46hFNu4sjHGTEaAnGa8P8HAQ). I've fixed most of the issue, like unsubscribing to `events` etc, but I now experience `EffectiveValueEntry`

[image]

In this particular case, The TabItem refers to the `ImageEditor` usercontrol. What should I look for? Why is this happening? How can I remove the EffectiveValueEntry[] instance?

Comment: Maybe you should somehow realease/dispose those `images` entries?

Comment: They are release, disposed and assigned to null

Comment: To me it seems that it is the `Popup` that is "leaked", e.g. you still have a reference to the `Popup` even though it no longer is used.

Comment: Does your `UserControl` initialize anything in the `Loaded` event of the `TabControl`?

Comment: Have you found any solution? Same issue here